# How to upload files using Ajax and Codeigniter without having Flash support?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, upload

I have tried to many javascript plugins but finally had to post this question. Which is the best way to upload files using PHP CodeIgniter framework & Ajax ?

Comment: if you google "ajax file upload", you will find tons of result.

Comment: unless you are only targeting modern browsers you're stuck with flash for "ajax" style uploading unless you use an iframe.

Comment: @safarov I have already tried a lot of times. This one was best but it work only if we have jquery 1.2 version. and current version of jquery is 1.7  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for everything now. Because it is mostly client side driven it runs on any almost any webbrowser and platform(.net,php,etc)

It uses clever ways of detecting browser compatibility; It tries to inject Flash objects or silverlight into the client to allow for functionality such as chunked uploads allowing for uploads greater than 2gb, with speed(kb/s), queue management, etc.

This is truly an amazing uploader.. but it is so under exposed that it took me years to find this. And now my sites (with a bit of perfectionist work) look like Google or Facebook styled uploaders.. [FOR FREE!](http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php)

[image]

Comment: required some study but its the best. supports all browsers. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ with great success in a web app. That was over a year ago, though. I used Kohana, not CI, but it's really agnostic on that matter.

Answer (score 0):

`ajax` does not natively support file uploads. you can achieve this by submitting a form to an iframe and reading the response. there are many plugins available which serves the functionality in an organized way.

Answer (score 0):

use this one : 
http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/Tinymce-Ajax-File-Manager/ ;)

Comment: hey @afsane, thanks for the plugin but it requires jquery 1.2 only :(